# remove extra zeros from string

Tags: java, regex, hive, hiveql

I would like write a regex expression to remove extra zeros from a string.

`REGEXP_REPLACE(REGEXP_REPLACE("Input_String","^0+", ''),'0+$','')` **fails if** `input_string = 120` then `output_string = 12` **instead of** `120`.

Below is the expected input vs output:

```
120--> 120
12--> 12
120.00--> 120
000329.0--> 329
14.4200--> 14.42
000430--> 430 
0.24000--> 0.24
0.100--> 0.1
1.0--> 1
```

Comment: Do you *really* want to do it with a regex ? It would be easier with `Double.parseDouble()`

Comment: @ArnaudDenoyelle `new BigDecimal(...)` would be better, in that it won't be lossy.

Comment: I need implement this in hive...so i was thinking of regex

Comment: Added solution for Hive using cast

Comment: You may use `^0+(?=[1-9])|\.0+$|(\.[0-9]*?)0+$` and replace with `$1`, see https://regex101.com/r/pzTk6z/1

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way is to use `BigDecimal`:

```
String stripped = new BigDecimal(input).stripTrailingZeros().toString();
```

---

Edit: this doesn't actually work for `000430`: the string representation of that is `4.3E+2`.

You can fix this by ensuring that the `scale` is at least zero:

```
BigDecimal b = new BigDecimal(input).stripTrailingZeros();
if (b.scale() < 0) {
  b = b.setScale(0, RoundingMode.UNNECESSARY);
}
String stripped = b.toString();
```

Comment: I need implement this in hive...so i was thinking of regex

Answer (score 1):

Regex are not always the best tool for that. In a real code, I would use Andy's solution. Now, if you really want to do it with a regex, here is one possible way to decompose it :

- beginning of the string : `^`
- take as much 0 as possible : `0*`
- **Start capture here** : `(`
- [0-9] as much as possible : `[0-9]*`
- character dot (must be escaped) : `\\.`
- [0-9] as **few** as possible : `[0-9]*?`
- **End capture here** : `)`
- as much 0 as possible : `0*`
- end of the string : `$`

Here is the code. Note : it does not handle integers but they can be handled in a similar way

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^0*([0-9]*\\.[0-9]*?)0*$");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher("010.02010");

if(matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println("group 1 : " + matcher.group(1));
}
```

**Output** :

```
group 1 : 10.0201
```

As you can see, parsing to a BigDecimal is more readable. Also, using a regex is not necessarily more efficient.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to do the same in Hive, use cast as **decimal** (adjust to maximum required precision/scale):

```
select cast(str as decimal(30,5)) as fixed_number
from
(--test dataset
select stack(9, 
'120',
'12',
'120.00',
'000329.0',
'14.4200',
'000430',
'0.24000',
'0.100',
'1.0'
) as str
)s;
```

Result:

```
OK
120
12
120
329
14.42
430
0.24
0.1
1
Time taken: 0.519 seconds, Fetched: 9 row(s)
```

Answer (score 0):

just save this file delete_ending_zeroes_udf.py in hadoop system with the following content.

## delete_ending_zeroes_udf.py

```
import sys
import string
import re

def delete_ending_zeroes(x):
    if '.' in x:
        y = re.sub("0+$","", str(x))
        if len(y.split('.')[1])==0:
            y = y.split('.')[0]
    else:
        y = re.sub("^0+","", str(x))
    return y



while True:
    line = sys.stdin.readline()
    if not line:
        break

    line = string.strip(line, "\n ")
    Input_String = line.strip()
    outut_string = delete_ending_zeroes(Input_String)
    print("\t".join([Input_String, outut_string]))
```

#

And write the following code in hive compilation

```
add file hdfs:///delete_ending_zeroes_udf.py;

SELECT TRANSFORM (Input_String)
    USING 'python delete_ending_zeroes_udf.py' AS
    (outut_string string)
FROM <your_hive_table>
```

reference: https://acadgild.com/blog/hive-udf-python

Comment: I need implement this in hive...so i was thinking of regex

Comment: Java/Hive != Python.

Comment: Python UDF can be used in hive. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/hdinsight/hadoop/python-udf-hdinsight#hivepython